# How to capture map with markers to canvas?

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I am using HERE maps in my web app and I would like to "take a screen shot" from the visible map. I am using the SDKs [H.Map.capture](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/maps/capture-map-area) function for this, but the problem is that it does not include the map markers (DOM Markers) on the result canvas.

How can I include the markers in the captured canvas?
Or is there another way to take a screen shot of the element including the map (html2canvas did not work).

This is what I need:

[image: So this is what I need as an image]

This is what I get:

[image: But with capture, this is what I get]

I get the canvas with (using Vue):

`this.map.capture(callback, [this.ui, this.markers], 0, 0, height, width)`

And in the callback function placing the canvas to an image:

`<img v-if="imgData" :src="imgData">`

...

Callback function does this:

```
this.imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
```